# Dynamically generate all products on a responsive view using Bootstrap's Grid system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, gridview

I want to generate all my products and their information on a page using bootstrap's grid system. I tried to generate three products in a row at first and it worked using the following code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">Listing products</h1>

    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <% if @a%3 == 0 %>
          <div class="row">
      <% end %>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image', size: '260x320') %>
                  <%= product.title %> <br/>
                  <%= product.price %> <br/>
                  <%= link_to 'Show', product %><br/>
                </div>
      <% @a = @a+1  %>
      <% if @a%3 == 0 %>
          </div><hr/>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

(`@a` is what I declared in the controller which is initially set to 0)

The code will not work anymore if I want to only display two or less products in a row using the grid system when the screen gets smaller.

Are there any better ideas to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are generating incorrect HTML markup. Try to use `each_slice`:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">Listing products</h1>

    <% @products.each_slice(3) do |products| %>
          <div class="row">
            <% products.each do |product| %>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image', size: '260x320') %>
                  <%= product.title %> <br/>
                  <%= product.price %> <br/>
                  <%= link_to 'Show', product %><br/>
                </div>
            <% end %>    
          </div>
          <hr/>
  <% end %>
</div>
```